# Как с SQLAlchemy подключиться к базе Postgres, запущенной в контейнере Docker

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy, контейнеры

Мне нужно создать таблицу в Postgres, для этого я хочу использовать SQLAlchemy. В одном контейнере у меня запущен проект с SQLAlchemy, а во втором Postgres запущена Postgres. для этого я создал такой docker-compose файл:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.0-alpine
    container_name: test_postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_value:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - google_api_orders/.env
  app:
    build: /google_api_orders
    restart: always
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - google_api_orders/.env
volumes:
  db_value:
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при попытке подключиться и создать новую таблицу:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:5432/orders_db')
engine.connect()
```

я получаю ошибку:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
```

Как правильно подключиться к базе, запущенной в контейнере Docker из другого контейнера?

Comment: ну так вам же в подключении нужно хост указать, а не имя контейнера. если контейнер развернут в докере на локальном компьютере, укажите что-то вроде 'postgresql+psycopg2://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:5432/orders_db' вместо 'postgresql+psycopg2://admin:admin@test_postgres:5432/orders_db'

Comment: @strawdog, а как быть, если база запущена в одном контейнере, а сам проект (из которого нужно подключиться к базе) во втором?

Comment: а какая разница?

Comment: @strawdog вариант, который вы предложили, работает, в случае если проект запущен локально и не работает, если проект запущен в контейнере, как и база данных.

Comment: ну так вы же должны указывать конкретный ip контейнера. https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/

Answer (score 0):

Почему не работает `127.0.0.1`. `docker compose` создаёт отдельную виртуальную сеть и подключает к ней контейнеры. В этой сети у контейнеров адреса вида `172.17.0.2` и `172.17.0.3`, но какой будет префикс для IP адресов, заранее предсказать нельзя ([на самом деле можно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose), но не нужно). Поэтому ваша база данных располагается не на `127.0.0.1`, а на `172.17.0.2`

`docker compose` поднимает DNS сервер, который раздаёт имена контейнерам. Добавьте к сервису `postgres` ключ `hostname: db`, тогда в строке подключения вы можете указать имя вместо IP адреса:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://admin:admin@db:5432/orders_db')
```

Имя хоста `db` обслужит встроенный DNS сервер докера.